# More access to 'interesting' section

Tags: feature-request

Would it be possible for it to be easier to access the 'interesting' questions? They are only displayed if you click the Stack Overflow logo. Clicking that shows a totaly different list than clicking questions.

It was initialy confusing that the two buttons generated different results.
I feel there should be more documentation on filter types in the faq or the two buttons did the same thing.

Comment: So you wan't something easier than a single click? hmmmm, tricky.

Comment: Seriously though, how could it be easier? Any suggestions?

Comment: It was initialy confusing to begin with and if it featured more, or there was more guidence, it would be easier. I don't see what is different between 'interesting' and 'questions' and why 'interesting' couldn't feature more seeing as many questions are relevent to you.

Comment: Then maybe you need to flesh out your question a bit more. You haven't made clear that you find it confusing, just that you want it to be 'easier', whatever that means.

Comment: @vascogotlost I think the main point is the "interesting/top questions" section isn't a "tab" like the other sections, it's not immediately apparent how to get back to it from say /questions

Comment: @BenBrocka you're probably right and I would tend to agree with that, but it isn't made apparent in the question, particularly before the edit.